# Trouble implementing recursion | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am having some trouble implementing recursion into some of my code and the task I have been given must be completed via recursion. Any help would be much appreciated.

Task 1 requires me to return the smallest value in a list through the use of recursion and I keep on getting an error

Code:

```
lst = [12, 1, 44, 61, 0]

def smallestNum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        raise ValueError("List is empty")
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        print(lst[0])
    return min(lst[0], smallestNum(lst[1:])

print(smallestNum(lst))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: List is empty
```

Comment: Using recursion for task 2 is awkward, at best.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought as well but I have to find some way of doing so even though I don't see why (requirement of the task)

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the first task.

```py
def smallestNum(lst):
    return min(lst[0],smallestNum(lst[1:])) if len(lst)>1 else lst[0]

lst = [12, 1, 30, 44, 61]
print(smallestNum(lst))
```